# Bill and Dan's Journey

Tags: story, steganography, english

What is this story about?

(Apologies if at the end I improperly announce the answer.)

> Bill and Dan bravely ventured forth, eagerly hiking towards a notorious outcrop. Traipsing through the water under a regal old acai, they espied a giant, squirming worm at the bottom of the tree. Pressing further on, they later saw a pink glow, as a solitary flamingo settled upon the water through which they carried their load. Finally they glimpsed a magnificent, soaring albatross.

---

Not part of the puzzle:

This is my first puzzling.se question; accordingly I have done my best with a fairly simple one, but please let me know if I am in error e.g. with the tags. Will add hints if it proves too tricky!

---

**Hint #1**

> The key (although perhaps a little tenuous) lies **within** the wording of my apology

---

**Hint #2**

> Apologies if at the **end** I **improper**ly an**noun**ce the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this story is about

> An adventure to the past

Step 1

> Following Hint 2
>  If we take the ends of the improper nouns, we have
>  outcro**p** wate**r** aca**i** wor**m** tre**e** glo**w**, flaming**o** wate**r** loa**d**. albatros**s**.
>  **prime words**

Step 2

> Taking the beginnings of words in prime number positions
>  Bill **a**nd **D**an bravely **v**entured forth, **e**agerly hiking towards a **n**otorious outcrop. **T**raipsing through the water **u**nder a **r**egal old acai, they **e**spied a giant, squirming worm at **t**he bottom **o**f the tree. Pressing further on, **t**hey later saw a **p**ink glow, **a**s a solitary flamingo **s**ettled upon the water through which **t**hey carried their load. Finally they **g**limpsed a **m**agnificent, soaring albatross.
>  which spells out
>  **Adventure to t past gm**

Comment: Well done! I had only intended "Adventure" (and hadn't bothered to count any primes past 23!), but it seems there's accidentally a semi coherent extension to my designed answer! Hope you enjoyed my first puzzle :)

Comment: @S.Dunnim Yes, it is a good one. I like how you hid the hint.